# Is there any way to make WhatsApp read data from shared storage root instead of from /Android folder in Android 11?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, file-management, android-11

I am fed up searching literally everywhere and on forums. It's been so many days since Android 11 was released and so many phones now run Android 11. But WhatsApp media and all data are moved to a new folder inside the Android folder.

So, it is very difficult to back up every time, and also the whole folder gets automatically deleted when I uninstall WhatsApp. And if I manually keep all the files inside the `/Android` folder only, WhatsApp is reading it. (Earlier, the folder used to be in the root itself). The problem is that in my Phone file manager (tried with multiple file managers), it is very difficult to deal with files in the `/Android` folder such as knowing their size or folder.

So, the WhatsApp folder inside the shared storage root folder itself instead of inside the `/Android` folder is very convenient. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: AFAIK, this is [a system restriction since Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Comment: Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Android 11 has limited (if not completely restricted) the users' access to the `/Android/data` folder(s). Even if WhatsApp developers tried to move the default `/data` storage to an SD card, it'll be quite a hazzle since they'll have to take special permissions from Google. So, the simple answer is no, you can't.

However, if you want to change the default storage location for the media folder(s), you can try a lot of apps, XInternalSD, though root is required for this.